# Choosing an aesthetics program

Tags: programs

Im 21M and have done a core strengthening program for the past 6 months to get to a reasonable base.

Even at the risk of ridicule but I really just want to get a glorified Abercrombie body over the next year(s) and I have a lot of time this summer to start.

So I was just wondering if anyone has recommendations as to a good program.

I found one posted by Pietro Boselli on his yt, which seemed good
https://www.liftrep.com/routines/pietro-boselli-a-week-of-workouts

Otherwise the Zyzz program or for all the cheese one posted by a former Abercrombie model
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnz3hnii0ndzw3y/WORKOUT%20GUIDE.docx

Genuinely not entirely sure if they're any good or where to start.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Don't know if you copy/pasted this from somewhere, but you can format your links regularly here.

Comment: @alec seems to be cross posted at https://www.reddit.com/r/workout/comments/ug6p2r/choosing_an_aesthetics_program/ and https://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=181328363   Both times in the last few hours.

Comment: @Criggie - There is nothing wrong with crossposting on different forums, just crossposting within the exchange network. However, I'm not sure this is a good fit here as it is technically a product recommendation request.

Comment: @JohnP totally, I'm just flexing my google-fu in public. Alec's commend piqued my interest.

Comment: I personally like to point the dupes because sometimes, it's been answered on one of those other sites.